# Meaning of shine (slang)

Tags: meaning

> Won't look back on my mind
>
> Won't let bad out my shine

This phrase from the song XXXTENTACION - Whoa. Honestly, I don't understand that at all. Can you please tell me what's it shine?
I can suppose that shine means famous, so he doesnt want bad things happens.

Comment: I think your guess is going to be as good as anyone's.

Comment: That song contains this gem: "I was like whoa-oh-oh".  @Дмитрий - you need to realise that in songs of this type, the words do not have to mean very much (or anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a later line of the same song, "Told my mom, I'm gon' shine," it means to excel, to live up to your potential, to do so well that other people notice.  In "won't let bad out my shine" it's likely that "out" is being used for "outdo" or "outstrip" or even "outshine".  Meaning he won't let bad things prevent him from shining/succeeding.